# Fullcalendar not showing events in month view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Here is what I do 
In week view Select 12 AM time slot on 30 Dec,2014 and then Select 01 January,2015 as end time. event is successfully created and shown in week view. Now when I switch to month view event is shown only on 30 Dec. Switching back to week view retains event correctly, week view works fine even on page refresh but month view never works.

I use Fullcalendar 1.6.1 version. http://fullcalendar.io/

**Code part**

```
 var day = new Date();

$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
  editable: true,
  events: events_list,
  //Adjusts ratio of calendar and makes it taller. Default is 1.35
  aspectRatio: 1.265,
  header: {
    right: "agendaDay,agendaWeek,month",
    center: "title",
    left: "prev,next today"
  },
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  allDaySlot: true,
  axisFormat: 'h(:mm)tt',
  slotMinutes: 15
 })
```

fullcalendar.js https://gist.github.com/1533e07d93f308a6b6b0.git

Comment: you have to provide relevant code in question

Comment: try to set allDayDefault: false,